# Kendo Grid cancelling an edit removes the row

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am struggling with the Kendo Grid and it's edit popup.

When I press edit it brings up the popup as expected but when I press cancel it removes the row instead of doing nothing.

My kendo grid is as follows:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.Where(x => x.OrgLevel == 0).First().DefinedFieldsList)
    .Name("DefinedlevelsGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {           
        columns.Bound(x => x.FieldName).Title("Name");
        columns.Bound(x => x.FieldTypeText).Title("Type");
        columns.Bound(x => x.isMandatory).Title("Mandatory");
        columns.Bound(x => x.DefaultValue).Title("Default Value");
        columns.Bound(x => x.UpdatedOn).Title("Updated");
        columns.Bound(x => x.LevelGuid).Hidden();
        columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); });
    })
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("_OrgDefinedFieldEdit"))
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Events(events => events.Edit("GetLevelGuid"))                
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Model(model =>
            {
                model.Id(x => x.FieldId);
                model.Field(x => x.UpdatedOn).DefaultValue(DateTime.Now.ToString());
                model.Field(x => x.LevelGuid);
                model.Field(x => x.FieldType).DefaultValue(1);
            })
        .Create(create => create.Action("CreateDefinedField", "OrganisationAjax"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("EditDefinedField", "OrganisationAjax"))
        .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("DeleteDefinedField", "OrganisationAjax"))
    )
    .ToolBar(commands => commands.Create())
)
```

I populate it using the model but then use a subsequent ajax request when ever an associated list of buttons is selected:

```
$(document).on('click', '.LevelSelector', function () {
    updateOrgDetails(this);
    var levelGuid = $(this).attr("LevelGuid").toString();

    var Url = '@Url.Action("GetLevelFields", "OrganisationAJAX")' + '?LevelGuid=' + levelGuid;

    $.ajax({
        url: Url,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        type: 'POST',
        context: this,
        timeout: 60000,
        dataType: 'json',
        tryCount: 0,
        retryLimit: 3,
        success: function (data) {

            var grid = $("#DefinedlevelsGrid").data("kendoGrid");
            grid.dataSource.data(data);
        },
        error: function (httpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $(".Message").text("Error: " + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

The data coming back matches the field names so I'm not really sure what the problem could be.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Edit: Here is a Json sample that is getting returned:

```
[{"FieldId":1,"FieldGuid":"12345","LevelId":3,"LevelGuid":"12345","FieldName":"Val","FieldType":1,"FieldTypeText":"Text","FieldTypeInput":null,"DefaultValue":"Val","Description":"Val","isMandatory":false,"CreatedOn":"1/12/2014 10:57","UpdatedOn":"1/12/2014 10:57","CreatedBy":"1","UpdatedValue":null,"HasData":false,"IsForAllSubNodes":true,"FieldTypesRef":[{"id":1,"Type":"Text"},{"id":2,"Type":"Numeric"},{"id":3,"Type":"Boolean"},{"id":4,"Type":"Date"}],"DefinedFieldData":null}
```

Comment: You are declaring that the `id` is a field called `Id`, did you check that you are receiving such `Id` from the server and it's value is different than `0` and `null`? Could you edit the original question and add an example of the JSON data received from the server?

Comment: Oh... no it's FieldId. But I thought I had to declare it as     model.id(x => x.FieldId);. Is that wrong?

Comment: Oops! sorry, my mistake you are right. Same question about `FieldId`, is it not `null`/`0`?

Comment: Nope not 0 or null. All FieldId's coming back with a value